# git fetch insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects?

Tags: git, permissions, file-permissions, git-fetch, directory-permissions

In my repo in my home directory (on an Ubuntu box) I did

```
 git fetch
```

I unfortunately got an error about:

```
 insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
```

There's a gazillion directories in .git/objects and all of them appear to be 775.  The few spot checks I did show the files to be 664.

I went and did a

```
 chmod -R 777 .git/objects
```

which fixed the problem but now I've got a bunch of files 777 on my box and I'm sure that's a no-no.

What should the correct permissions be and how can I easily get all 10 million files and directories set correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Are you the owner of all the files?

Try

```
chown -R you:you .git
```

Then chmod them to "normal"

```
chmod -R u=rwX,g=rwX,o=
```

Comment: On Mac: chown -R you:staff .git was enough in my case

Comment: On Mac: chown -R user .git was also enough in my case

Comment: Just encountered this on a local repo that was previously working fine, no permissions/group changes that I know of. What in the world caused this?